# Не работает window.onunload в некоторых браузерах

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, frontend

В chrome window.onunload  отлично работает, но в Firefox и Opera оно не работает.Почему?Как мне это исправить?Вот код:

```
window.onunload = function(){
    let elems = document.getElementsByClassName("take");
    let dict = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        dict[String(elems[i].src)] = elems[i].tagName;
    }
    let json = JSON.stringify(dict);
    console.log(json)
    fetch('/delete',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: json
    });
};
```

Comment: ну вот так она работает. Не стоит на него полагаться..... А еще попробуйте `onbeforeunload`. Но это тоже не надёжная вещь, увы

Comment: а можно еще как-то следить за закрытием страницы?Чтобы и в других браузерах работало?

Comment: ЕМНИП, до сих пор не придумали таких решений. Да чтоб ещё и на всё. Потому что это потенциальная дырка для хацкеров и баннеров

Comment: а как вы узнаете, что оно не работает? Запрос не доходит до сервера?